# Get all unique tags from tumblr blog

Tags: javascript, tumblr

There are ways to get Posts and other details using tags, from your Tumblr Blog, and Vice Versa as per **[Tumblr API V2](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)**

I want to get a list of all tags (unique tags) irrespective of blog posts

So If I have **10** posts tagged **`Technology`**, **`Web`** and **3** posts tagged **`JavaScript`**, **`Web`** 
- I want to query my blog in such a way that it gives me `Technology`, `Web` and `JavaScript`

Say for eg., an array - `results.posts.tags = ["Technology", "Web", "JavaScript"]`
or an Object, which I can dig in to find the `tags` and then iterate in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the Tumblr API, but it looks like you should be able to build a list of tags - but there is no built in method for it. First you'll have to find the total # of posts in the blog by querying the `/info` method<sup>1</sup>. The URL for that is:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/info?api_key={key}
```

Taking the response from that and decoding it into an object (jQuery, extjs, w/e will work) you can find the `posts` field for the total # of posts. Using that you can start to pull back the posts 20 at a time, the max according to the API, using the `/posts` method. The URL for that is:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts[/type]?api_key={key}&[optional-params=]
```

You probably want to omit `/type`, but you will need to specify `offset` in the optional-params. With the offset you can just work through all the posts, 20 at a time<sup>2</sup>, until you have downloaded them all (the number you got from the `/info` query).  As you download the posts just keep track of which tags you get.

It's kind of unfortunate you have to download the body of the post just to get the tag list, but I don't see any other method that gives you the tags, or a option to supress the body and just see the meta-data for posts.

****EDIT****

<sup>1</sup>: Per Felix's comment the # of posts `/info` returns is known to be slightly off sometimes. In the case where the expected number is high, you need to make sure you are only looping over results you actually received, not what you anticipated. To handle the case where the expected number is low, you could do one query past what the end should be and see if you get any results back. At that point though you might consider dropping the `/info` query all together and just querying `/posts` until you don't get any more results.

<sup>2</sup>: Per Felix's second comment, even though the API lists the range of values for how many posts you can pull down at once as `1-20` with `20` default, supposedly it will accept up to `50`. Pulling 50 results at a time could speed things up / lower your bandwidth, but it will make your code more complicated to do right.  Since it is an undocumented feature (read: might just be a bug) there is no guarantee it will keep working. So you could try to query 50 at a time, but need to be prepared to handle a `400` error code, or something similar, in case they make their service match the API and then default back to 20.

Comment: Thats the obvious last resort I did not want to jump to. I didn't want to stress querying and stress my JavaScript for the same by looping, etc. Thanks for reply. It seems the only way right now

Comment: @OmShankar, This is really the only way to do this.  However, **one note**: you can actually fetch **50** posts at a time by specifying `&limit=50` in the query string, and increasing your `offset` by 50 each time :)  This is an undocumented API feature.

Comment: One additional note: it is a [**known bug**](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tumblr-api/ZOkrxlUKIc8/discussion) that the _total post count_ (in the field `posts` returned from calling `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/info?...` is very often incorrect.  In addition, calling `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/.../posts` also returns a field called `total_posts` and _this number_ is also often _incorrect_. It will get you somewhere _close_ to the total, but don't count on it being accureate.

Comment: @FelixBonkoski Good notes on both. 50 vs 25 posts at a time could make a huge difference on some blogs.  And the bug is kind of a pain =/  You can deal with it by checking your expected # of results vs what you actually got back, but it would be so much cleaner if they just fixed it =)

Comment: Thanks all for valuable info. I actually want to dynamically create menus using JS/jQuery for the most used/favorite tags. So that when the user comes on my blog, user can jump to those tags directly, saving self from the clutter. But now I think, I should hard-code the menu items

Comment: @OmShankar hardcoding them would probably work unless the tags you use change constantly. Another idea would be to pick a time interval (nightly maybe?) to run a java app/shell script/ruby script/whatever works on your system to figure out the common tags and throw them in a database table. Then you do a little AJAX when the page loads and pull down the "current" most used tags. Sure the list of tags is a couple hours to a day outdated, but that way your users aren't waiting each time the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of how it works, but it does: look at the [Tumblr tag list bookmarklet](http://root.patrickbeser.com/tumblr/tags/). Should give you at least some code you can use.

Comment: It only works in the Edit/Create Post. At that time Tumblr gives you a JS object that has been populated with unique tags

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but I thought it might be useful for some people as I've taken the time to make this into a javascript which returns all the unique tags as a javascript object.

https://github.com/scintillate/tumblrtag/